# If you are working in the paradigm of NHST, what steps should you take in response to a p value of .049?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

Ignore for a moment the issues with NHST.

If a study returns a p value very close to .05 (assuming this is the cutoff one is using), what are some steps one can take to ensure the results are valid? Two that come to mind are: examining effect size and power. Are there any others?

Comment: You implicitly suppose the results might not be "valid": in what way?

Comment: With a p value so close to the cutoff, I worry that the effect may not be robust, and that if run again it might have a p value > .05.

Comment: By "not be robust" it sounds like you don't really intend to use 0.05 as the threshold, then.  The issue about a new result not being significant is one of the (better known of the) "issues with NHST" to which you refer.  In effect, your first line has ruled out just about anything except a trivial response, because you basically are telling us "Ignore the issues with NHST, but I want to ask about an issue with NHST!"

Comment: Are there no approaches within the NHST paradigm that could help? Cross-validation?

Comment: There's nothing in the NHST paradigm that needs help here.  If your p-value is less than your threshold, you reject the null hypothesis.  (I'm not defending this--I'm just stating it as a fact, with the implicit assumption that the experiment was well designed, the statistical model is a good one, etc, etc.)

Comment: Your use of "robust" would seem to imply you wanting some assurance you'd get the same result (reject again) if you repeated your analysis on a new sample. There's nothing that would guarantee that. You may find the histograms in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889700/why-do-t-tests-on-the-same-distribution-can-give-me-a-p-value-near-zero/2893786#2893786) may help clarify why (one for a true null, one for a false null) -- in either case both very large and very small p-values are unsurprising.